# Excel VBA Multiple discrete worksheet change events

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to incorporate multiple separate worksheet change events on a single worksheet, in relation to showing/hiding checkboxes.

The following code works fine for a single change event but subsequent change events are ignored.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

If ActiveSheet.Range("L7").Value = "0" Then

ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 11").Visible = False

Else

ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 11").Visible = True

End If

If ActiveSheet.Range("g17").Value = "0" Then

ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 16").Visible = False

Else

ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("Check Box 16").Visible = True

End If

End Sub
```

What is the best method for referencing multiple worksheet change events?

Comment: So you want to manage the show/hide of both check boxes in a single sheet change event?

Comment: The checkboxes are independent of each other.  This is for an end-user checklist which shows/hides cells and checkboxes.

Comment: Based on the user action on the individual cells, the check boxes will be displayed or hidden. So what exactly is the issue here?

Comment: Worksheet change doesn't allow for more than one event.

Comment: It doesn't allow more than one event but in your code, you are performing a single event only. If you select both cells and change the value to 0 or 1, then both checkboxes will be affected at once. If you change one cell, only the corresponding checkbox will be affected.

Comment: I'm referencing two changes events, one at L7 and the other at G17.  The current code deal with the first event at L7 but any changes to the second event at G17 are ignored.

Comment: Its because you are only changing one cell at a time in your sheet. So if you change the value of L7, Check Box 11 is affected. As I said, select both cells (Ctrl+Select) and type 0 or 1 and press Ctrl+Enter and you will see that both check boxes will be affected. Its the logic of your code which is making you think that only one change is done - because technically you are performing only one change at a time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158094/discussion-between-alanb-and-pankaj-jaju).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your provided code, something like this should work for you:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim CheckBoxName As String

    Select Case Target.Address(0, 0)
        Case "L7":  CheckBoxName = "Check Box 11"
        Case "G17": CheckBoxName = "Check Box 16"
    End Select

    Me.Shapes(CheckBoxName).Visible = (Target.Value <> 0)

End Sub
```

Comment: @tigeravator - thank you for the code but I am getting an error message that Method 'Checkboxes' of object' _Worksheet' failed.  Target.Address is referencing cell H5.

Comment: @AlanB See edit, I changed the code from `Me.CheckBoxes` to `Me.Shapes` which should correct the issue.

Comment: @tigeravator - that has removed the error but the checkboxes now don't hide if the target value is zero.

Comment: @AlanB it works for me.  If it's not working for you, make sure the check box names are correct and that they are on the same sheet where you're making the cell value changes, and that you are editing the correct cells.

Comment: @tigeravator -  I think this is down to the method I'm using to change the 0 to 1.  This is a separate drop-down to select a value, which then changes the cell I'm referencing to 0 or 1, using a formula in cell L7 or G17.  If I manually change 0 to 1, the checkbox appears or disappears as required but using the drop-down has no effect.  Is it possible to extend your code to work with this?

Comment: Yes, my original code works but for only a single event.  Is it possible to amend my code to work for multiple events, or your code to work in this way?